# Secure file downloading with Express.js/Node.js

Tags: node.js, express, download

In my app logged-in users can download pdf files. But what I need is not only to restrict downloading files to authorised users, but also secure file downloading in a way, that authorised users can not figure out possible names for other files. 
E.g.

```
/files/fileName1.pdf
/files/fileName2.pdf
/files/fileName3.pdf
```

This is a very primitive example to demonstrate a case when it may be easy to guess names for other files.

A possible solution for this could be adding a hash to each file name which I want to avoid in order to have readable files names.

Another solution could be to create a hash or and _id of a record where the file name is stored (mongodb ids look complicated) for each and every file and use it in the url as a parameter.
E.g.

```
/files/da39a3ee5e6b4b0d3255bfef95601890afd80709/fileName1.pdf
```

In that case to download fileName2.pdf one would need a hash which is unrealistic to guess.

But I wonder if there is a better solutions for this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [passport.js](http://passportjs.org/) to write an identification+authentication+authorization mechanism.

But I guess you don't want to loose time implementing things that many others have already done. Have a look at the [mean.js](http://meanjs.org/) project generator. It generates you a node project with a mechanism to register, authenticate, etc.

Have fun!

Comment: I have it all. My only concern is a secure file downloading process

Comment: Secure only means "at a security level you accept". I like the solution of the unguessable URL, and I have already used it in a project. If an URL contains a UUDI for instance, you could consider it as unguessable.

Answer (score 0):

Chance.js is a minimalist generator of random strings, numbers, etc. to help reduce some monotony particularly while writing automated tests or anywhere else you need anything random.
http://chancejs.com/